# Recycler view refreshing continuously

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I had a single recycler view in MainActivity.I'm adding items to that recycler view from sqlite database. The problem is that it is refreshing continuously when we press back button from app and come back to app again.It is adding duplicates of existing items.

Here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package bk.acs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import bk.acs.AddingToDatabase.MyDialog;
import bk.acs.RecyclerView.Data;
import bk.acs.RecyclerView.ListItem;
import bk.acs.RecyclerView.MyAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CONTACTS_PERMISSION = 10;
    RecyclerView recview;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    Data d;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationDrawer drawer;
    String appName;
    LinearLayout main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        recview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recview);
        drawer = (NavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navDrawer);
        drawer.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
        d = new Data(this);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(d.getList(), this);
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recview.getContext()));
        recview.setAdapter(adapter);
        main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
        try {
            createFolders();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int res_id = item.getItemId();
        if (res_id == R.id.refresh) {
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void updateRecView(long num, String subname) {
        disableRecView();
        adapter.listdata.add(new ListItem(subname, num + ""));
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.listdata.size());
    }

    public void disableRecView() {
        main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
        main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void createFolders() throws IOException {
        File mainFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath(), appName);
        File inputs = new File(mainFolder, "Inputs");
        File outputs = new File(mainFolder, "Outputs");
        if (mainFolder.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File temp = new File(inputs, "temp.txt");
            temp.createNewFile();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Creating Folders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainFolder.mkdir();
            inputs.mkdir();
            outputs.mkdir();
            File temp = new File(inputs, "temp.txt");
            temp.createNewFile();
        }
    }

    public void fetchDataForSub(String s) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity1.class);
        intent.putExtra("tv", s);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is my Data.java file from where I'm getting items from database

```
package bk.acs.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import bk.acs.MainActivity;
import bk.acs.databases.Main;

/**
 * Created by bk on 01-03-2017.
 */

public class Data {
    public static ArrayList<String> sample = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] cols = {"SubjectName"};
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context ctx;

    public Data(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
        Main main = new Main(context, "subjects_db", 1, 1);
        db = main.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("SubjectsTable", cols, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            sample.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        if (sample.size() != 0) {
            ((MainActivity) context).disableRecView();
        }
    }

    public List getList() {

        for (int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++) {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem(sample.get(i), (i + 1) + ""); //Fixed crash
            list.add(listItem);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

This is MyAdapter.java file

```
package bk.acs.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import bk.acs.MainActivity;
import bk.acs.R;
import bk.acs.SubActivity1;

/**
 * Created by bk on 01-03-2017.
 */

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.Holder> {
    public List<ListItem> listdata;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context c;

    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> list, Context c) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        listdata = list;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subjects_li, parent, false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        ListItem item = listdata.get(position);
        holder.subjectName.setText(item.subName);
        holder.serialNo.setText(item.sno);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listdata.size();
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView subjectName;
        TextView serialNo;
        View container;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            subjectName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectTitle);
            serialNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sno);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_root);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity) c).fetchDataForSub(subjectName.getText().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

How can I prevent duplicates from getting added to this recycler view..Thanks in advance

Comment: you can prevent this by making the list not static

Answer (score 1):

Because `public static List<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<>();`,
is always added, so you need to clear the list before you add the items.

```
    public List getList() {
    list.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++) {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem(sample.get(i), (i + 1) + ""); //Fixed crash
        list.add(listItem);
    }
    return list;
}
```